# Access pixel value of matrix A

Tags: opencv

How to get the value of a pixel in OpenCV without knowing the channel depth? For example in the following example I have to know beforehand that the matrix a has three channels.

```
Mat a;
Vec3b pixel=a.at<Vec3b>(0,0);
```

How can I write a function that can read both 1 channel matrix and 3 channel matrix? I'm planning to hold feature vectors in matrix, so it can also be an arbitrary constant number.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511715/opencv-indexing-through-mat-of-unknown-type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation for [at](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-at). If you want to select a channel from a 3 channel floating point image you'd do it as such:

```
float pixel = img.at<float>(i,j,k); //i - row, j - col, k - channel
```

You can check number of channels using

```
int nChannels = img.channels();
```